# How convert .net.xml successfully using netconvert?

Tags: xml, traffic-simulation, sumo

I am new to SUMO-GUI and its command line. I was trying to create road network and in order to do that I created .con.xml,.edg.xml,.nod.xml,.typ.xml and netc.cfg file. 
Now I tried to run "**netconvert –c quickstart.netccfg"**
command where file files were stored and I bumped into the error which I have attached images. I am using Windows 8 platform.
Anybody is there to help. I am really in the big trouble with this.[This is command line output where the error is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEhc1.png) and 
[List of file in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otWgR.png)

Note: I referred sumo user docs for creating the network.

Answer (score 2):

netconvert seems to hiccup on parsing the parameter list. Especially the "-" before the c in "-c" seems to be a problem. Is this a standard hyphen? If you copied it from the webpage and pasted it into the command line try again with entering it via the keyboard.